# Remove dependency between Sql Server and Installshield

Tags: sql-server

How can I remove the dependency between Sql Server and Installshield 2010? I just want to install the Crystal Report **OurCrystalReport_x86**.

[image]

Thank you for your suggestions.

Comment: The error message seems fairly straightforward. The software you're trying to install (MiraSoftAccounting) requires that SQL Server be installed as a dependency. This is a decision that software vendor made. I'm not sure I understand your question

Comment: What happens if you click install?

Answer (score 1):

This is not an Installshield issue. And it isn't database related. Your problem has to do with the requirements of the product you are installing.

**MiraSoftAccounting**

The MiraSoftAccount software requires the following products:

- OurCrystalReport_x86
- Microsoft SQL Server 2008 Express SP1 (...

Depending on the software package created with InstallShield, they might be shipped with the MiraSoftAccounting ISO/installation, or you might have to install them prioor to installing the software.

Based on your question I am assuming that the products/requirements are shipped with the installation package.

Based on my knowledge of InstallShield, you can't remove the dependencies in the packages unless they are listed in a `setup.ini` file that came with your installation.

If you don't have a `setup.ini` file for your installation, then you are stuck.

#### Possible Solution 1

1. Install the MiraSoftAccounting package with all dependencies
2. De-install **SQL Server 2008 Express  SP 1** after installation

#### Possible Solution 2

1. Modify setup.ini file if available
2. Run installation of MiraSoftAccounting software

   - dependencies might have been removed

Best of luck.